# WPF Listview Selection ClickMode

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I was wondering if an item in ListView could be selected when Mouse Release, not Mouse Down. (Like ClickMode property of Buttons) Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register to `PreviewMouseDown` on the list and set `e.Handled=true`. Register to `PreviewMouseUp` and handle the selection manually. This should do what you're looking for.

But beware that such a list-behaviour confuses the user.